# Lilypond-book seems to skip included files

Tags: lilypond

I am experimenting with using Lilypond from windows.
It seems lilypond-book skips sub-files.

I created a minimum working/not-working example in main.lytex, which I'm processing with a CMD-file (see below).

The first two versions (lilypond-environment and lilypondfile) work, while the third one (included in sub-file) doesn't:

[image]

**Any ideas, why it won't work?**
Should I perhaps put all subfiles into a subdirectory and tell lilypond-book to process all files in this directory? (How?)
Did I miss to tell lilypond-book to include a specific directory?

**Notes:**

- on Linux it works (using `\input` instead of `\include`)
- on OS it works (using `\input` instead of `\include`)

*main.lytex*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{Lilypond directly}
\begin{lilypond}
    \relative c'
    {
      c4 d e f | g1
    }
\end{lilypond}

\section{Lilypond via include}
\lilypondfile{sheet.ly}

\section{Lilypond included from subfile}
\include{sub}

\end{document}
```

*sub.tex:*

```
\lilypondfile{sheet.ly}
```

*sheet.ly:*

```
\version "2.16.2"

\score {
  <<
    \relative c'
    {
      c4 d e f | g1
    }
  >>
}
```

*my CMD-file:*

```
set "outputdir=out"
set "includedir=inc"
set "maindir=%CD%"
set "mainfile=main"
set "TEXINPUTS=%TEXINPUTS%;%CD%"

set "lytexfile=%mainfile%.lytex"
set "latexfile=%mainfile%.tex"
set "pdffile=%mainfile%.pdf"

lilypond-book --pdf --output=%outputdir% --loglevel=ERROR %lytexfile% 

cd %outputdir%
pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode --include-directory=%maindir% %latexfile%

cp %pdffile% ../%pdffile%
cd ..
```

*output on command line:*

```
D:\path_to_working_dir>createPDF.cmd
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(D:\path_to_working_dir\out\main.tex
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, arabic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, galician, german, german-x-2009-06-19, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, icelandic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usenglishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")))
(D:\path_to_working_dir\out\main.aux)
(C:\Users\hardmooth\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (D:\path_to_working_dir\out\87/lily-da14f453-systems.tex

)
(D:\path_to_working_dir\out\05/lily-f1bfdfe8-systems.tex

) [1{C:/Users/hardmooth/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pd
ftex/config/pdftex.map}  ] (D:\path_to_working_dir\out\sub.tex
(D:\path_to_working_dir\out\46/lily-dc205d25-systems.tex

! LaTeX Error: File `46/lily-dc205d25-1' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.1 \includegraphics{46/lily-dc205d25-1}
                                        %
)) [2] (D:\path_to_working_dir\out\main.aux
(D:\path_to_working_dir\out\sub.aux)) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on main.pdf (2 pages, 37499 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.
```

Comment: Does it also fail if you use `\input` in place of `\include`?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: neither `\input` nor `\include` work. Besides the obvious difference that include results in a pagebreak, input adds an extra `lilypond-book.py: error: file not found: sub` as error

Comment: With `\input` instead of `\include` it works in my environment:
OS 10.8.5, TexShop with Lilypond-book engine by N. Vitacolonna.

Comment: for now I've switched to a virtual linux. That's working and I have more control, but it's not what I was looking for.

Comment: Have you tried to write `\input{sub.tex}` instead of `\input{sub}` ?

Answer (score 0):

With `lyluatex`, included files work. *main.lytex* should be renamed *main.tex*, and modified to include `lyluatex` package:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lyluatex}

\begin{document}

\section{Lilypond directly}
\begin{lilypond}
    \relative c'
    {
      c4 d e f | g1
    }
\end{lilypond}

\section{Lilypond via include}
\lilypondfile{sheet.ly}

\section{Lilypond included from subfile}
\include{sub}

\end{document}
```

Other files stay as in the question. Compilation should be done with `lualatex` and `-shell-escape` (no preprocessor command is required):

```sh
lualatex -shell-escape main
```